# How to find a suitable statement for the RHS(right hand side)?

Tags: logic

The question was as follows

Find a suitable statement for the RHS(right hand side) with two or fewer variables

[ (a or b $\implies$ c or d) and (c $\implies$ a) ] $\implies$

What is the method to solve such problems?

Comment: You can always put a tautology there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try test cases and keep track in a truth table, and see if you can spot any patterns in the results.

For example, what can you conclude about $a$ and $d$ if $c$ and $b$ are true? What if only $c$ is true? What can you conclude about $c$ if $a$ is false?

Comment: Then, is $d \implies c$ a suitable statement?

Comment: How did you arrive at that statement?

Comment: My suggestion was wrong. I don't get any pattern :( Btw this was a structured question if it helps...

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What conclusions can you make for the cases I've suggested above? (Suppose $c$ and $b$ are true; comment about $a$ and $d$.)